# Trying to get output in a list but i am getting as a single string

Tags: python, string

how can i get a string in three seprate string inside a list

```
  '''   Trying to get output in a list 
   "[“M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd.”, 
    “M/s Godfrey Philips”, 
    “M/s VST Industries”] '''


string ="M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd.,  Godfrey Philips, VST Industries"
    
    def process(string):
        if string.startswith("M/s"):
          return '\n'.join(f'{i}. {p.strip()}'
                           for i, p in enumerate(string.split(',')))
        else:
          return [string]
    
    print((process(string)));
```

#not getting output

Comment: join function returns a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
string ="M/s Indian Tobacco Co. pvt. ltd.,  Godfrey Philips, VST Industries"
    
def process(str):
    if string.startswith("M/s"):
        str = str.replace("M/s ", '') # EDIT replace "M/s"
        str = str.replace("  ", ' ')  # EDIT remove double spaces
        list = str.split(', ')        # create List, seperating with ","
        retList = ["M/s " + x for x in list]  # EDIT add "M/s" to all
        return(retList)
    else:
        return [string]

print((process(string)))
```